# Difference between double equals and triple equals for String Comparison in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I was reading a book on Elixir: [Introducing Elixir](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030584.do).

On string compare it says that:

> Elixir offers two options for comparing string equality, `==` and `===` operators. The `==` operator is generally the simplest though the other produces the same result.

Whats the purpose of having two operators if they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One example that comes to mind is floats - which use the same comparison functions as strings:

```
iex> 1 == 1    #true
iex> 1 == 1.0  #true
iex> 1 === 1   #true
iex> 1 === 1.0 #false
```

And for !==

```
iex> 1 != 2    #true
iex> 1 != 1.0  #false
iex> 1 !== 2   #true
iex> 1 !== 1.0 #true
```

It is worth noting that these functions use the following Erlang expressions:

```
Elixir | Erlang
==     | ==
===    | =:=
!=     | /=
!==    | =/=
```

From the [Erlang documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80197):

> When comparing an integer to a float, the term with the lesser precision is converted into the type of the other term, unless the operator is one of =:= or =/=. A float is more precise than an integer until all significant figures of the float are to the left of the decimal point. This happens when the float is larger/smaller than +/-9007199254740992.0. The conversion strategy is changed depending on the size of the float because otherwise comparison of large floats and integers would lose their transitivity.

Comment: Yes, `==` and `===` only affect the comparison between numbers.