# What is the difference between == and === in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I am starting out with Elixir. I read that Elixir has weak equality `==` and strict equality `===` operator.

Coming from the JavaScript background, `==` feels like a big mistake. Is it any different in Elixir? Am missing something? When should I use weak and strong operator respectively in Elixir?

So far I know, In JavaScript `"1" == 1` yields `true` while in Elixir it yields `false`. It means at least type information is preserved. If this is so, then what is the use of weak equality?

Comment: Seems already asked question you can get the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347090/difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals-for-string-comparision-in-eli)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between double equals and triple equals for String Comparision in elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347090/difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals-for-string-comparision-in-eli)

Comment: Well, I tried searching for this before. It talks about only string. But maybe considered duplicate as both explanations are good but context is different.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-operators.html):

> The difference between `==` and `===` is that the latter is more strict when comparing integers and floats:
>
> ```
> iex> 1 == 1.0
> true
> iex> 1 === 1.0
> false
> ```

Otherwise they're pretty much the same:

```
→ iex
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> "bro" == "bro"
true
iex(2)> "bro" ===  "bro"
true
iex(3)> 1 == 1
true
iex(4)> 1.0 == 1.0
true
iex(5)> 1 == 1.0
true
iex(6)> 1 === 1.0
false
```

Comment: Do you mean to say it is applicable only in case of numeric data types? For rest of the types, weak and strict behave same.

Comment: @HarshalPatil Yes, that's what I'm saying and it's also what the linked documentation is saying. I wholeheartedly suggest you read it.