# Does Elixir actually need two sets of equality operators (normal and strict)?

Tags: elixir

I am learning Elixir and have just learned about the two pairs of equality operators, `==`, `!=` and `===`, and `!==`. I think it was a mistake for Elixir to have two sets of equality operators. They created a 'strict' equality operator for the cases where ints and floats are compared. Note that this case of ints and floats being compared by value is an exception to how the operator normally works when two differing types are being compared which results in type comparison, not value comparison.
So we have made an exception to type comparison rule and added two operators to support that exception. What is the pay off? So ints and floats can be compared by value which is an operation most consider bad programming practice and is also rare.

The function of the strict equality operator should exist in the normal operator. That way when any two differing types are compared the behavior would be uniform. There would be no special case for ints and floats where the value of lesser precision gets converted into the other type and subsequently compared by value. This chart would need to be updated

`number < atom < reference < function < port < pid < tuple < map < list < bitstring`
to be something like this,

`ints < floats < atom < reference < function < port < pid < tuple < map < list < bitstring`.

Now we don't need an extra pair of operators and we have removed an exception that occurs when ints and floats are compared leaving us with a uniform rule for type comparison.

If ints and floats need to be compared they can undergo a conversion / cast before the comparison operation occurs.

What was the reason for adding two additional sets of equality operators when they could have packaged all the needed functionality into one pair of equality operators, `==` and `!=`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between double equals and triple equals for String Comparision in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32347090/difference-between-double-equals-and-triple-equals-for-string-comparision-in-eli)

Comment: The question you linked to @rsjaffe asks HOW the two pairs of equality operators are different. My question is WHY did the creators of Elixir choose to add the two sets of operators to the language when it seemed they could have been better off with one.

Comment: I think there is significant overlap, because the how is related to the why, but I see your point too. I've removed the duplicate flag.

Answer (score 2):

Elixir needs to be compatible with Erlang. Erlang had this behavior and depends on it in a few places in the language.

With the updated chart you provided, both `8 > 1.5` and `8 == 8.0` would return false, which really doesn't make sense since they're both numbers and CAN be compared mathematically.

I do agree with you that it's extremely rare (if ever) that you would compare integers to floats (I don't remember I've done it before honestly in over 15 years of development), but the language uses this internally to make the most sense out of the operator and, by design, provides you with this operator for your own use.

Comment: Found [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-lang-core/knmTBwkem0g/bSBrGiOwXTYJ) by Eric Meadows-Jönsson which might help also in the explanation.